# Return a column heading from a table for a specific cell

Tags: excel

I'm currently fighting excel to help me code data for some research I am doing.
I have a table that looks like this:

```
1       2       3       4
pete    jim     dave    alan
julie   sarah   helen   anita
```

I want to find the function that takes an name as an input and returns the cell heading that name can be found in the table.

E.g. If the input is 'julie', my output should be 1.

I've tried hlookup, match and index functions, but they seem to need a row specifying first. Rather than a look up from the entire table.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:D3="julie")*A1:D1)
```

Note: It will potentially give you the wrong value if you have duplicate names in your table - but for your example, this certainly works.

Comment: That's brilliant thanks - does exactly what I need it to. I'm curious - how does the formula work?

Answer (score 1):

If your headers are not numbers then use this, or if your data has duplicates and you only want to return the first row that has the match:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$2:$D$3)/($A$2:$D$3="julie"),1))
```

Comment: That's a much better answer!